# QML QtGraphicalEffect are not rendered in target machine

Tags: qt, graphics, qml

I wrote a minimal example that display an `Image` and a `DropShadow`:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    color: "black"

    Image {
        id: imgBackground
        source: "file:///path-to-background.png"

        Image {
            id: imgSpinner
            source: "file:///path-to-spinner.png"
            x: imgBackground.width / 2 - imgSpinUp.width / 2
            y: 260
            visible: false
            antialiasing: true
        }

        DropShadow {
             id: sdwSpinner
             anchors.fill: imgSpinner
             horizontalOffset: 8
             verticalOffset: 8
             radius: 4.0
             samples: 17
             color: "#AA000000"
             source: imgSpinner
        }
    }
}
```

In the development machine all works fine: I see the image with its shadow as expected. Now I want to deploy it on a target computer.
To find the needed file I created a virtual machine with a fresh install of the operating system and tried to run my application. Works as expected, fine!

Eventually, I deployed the same file to my customer machine... here the `DropShadow` is not rendered! If I set the `visible` property of the image I can see it (i.e. the paths are ok). Hence are the `QtGraphicalEffects` that don't work.

All the three machines (development, virtual machine, customer's computer) run the same o.s.: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.
The Qt version is 5.9 MinGW.

Here the files I deployed:

```
imageformats/
images/
platforms/
QtGraphicalEffect/
QtQml/
QtQuick/
QtQuick.2/
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
libstdc++-6.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll
opengl32sw.dll
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Network.dll
Qt5Qml.dll
Qt5Quick.dll
myapplication.exe
```

The development / virtual machine video card is a GeForce GTX 670, the customer one is an Intel GMA 4500.

What could prevent the rendering of such an item?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like an openGL issue.

> Note: Some effects may not be available with all graphics APIs.
>   OpenGL, which is used by default in most cases, has full support for
>   all of them. However, the software backend for instance does not
>   support effects at all. Therefore, when running with graphics APIs
>   other than OpenGL, refer to the documentation of the QML types in
>   question to check if the effect is available. For more information on
>   the Qt Quick scene graph backends, see Scene Graph Adaptations.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgraphicaleffects-index.html

Comment: Is there a way to check if an effect is available? I mean programmatically, without looking at it with my own eyes...